# Реализация сайта в консоли на С++

Tags: c++

Нужно сделать реализацию сайта продажи билетов в консоли с помощью метода "фабрика". И сделать окна создания и удаления объектов класса, тоже в С++, не через Qt. Подскажите реализацию этих окон пожалуйста, не понятно как их реализовывать. Вот код, который сейчас у меня есть:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

    class Ticket
    {
    private:
        int price;
        std::string ticketClass;
        bool baggage;
        bool availability;
        bool food;
    public:
        void setPrice(int p){
        this->price = p;
        }
        void setTicketClass(std::string cl){
        this->ticketClass = cl;
        }
        void setBaggage(bool b){
        this->baggage = b;
        }
        void setAvailability(bool a){
        this->availability = a;
        }
        void setFood(bool f){
        this->food = f;
        }
        int getPrice(){
        return price;
        }
        std::string getClass(){
        return ticketClass;
        }
        void getBaggage(){
        if(baggage){
            std::cout<<"baggage included"<<std::endl;
        }
        else{
            std::cout<<"baggage isn't included"<<std::endl;
    }
        }
        void getAvailability(){
        if(availability){
            std::cout<<"the ticket is available"<<std::endl;
        }else {
        std::cout<<"the ticket isn't avaliable"<<std::endl;}
        }
        void getFood(){
        if(food){
            std::cout<<"food is included"<<std::endl;
        }else {
        std::cout<<"food isn't included"<<std::endl;}
        }
    };

    class Flight
    {
    private:
        std::vector <Ticket>tickets;
        std::string company;
        std::string takeoffCity;
        std::string landingCity;
        std::string flightDate;
        int hours;
        int minutes;
        int flightNumber;
        int amountofseats;
    public:
        void setCompany(std::string c){
        this->company = c;
        }
        void setTakeOffCity(std::string t_city){
        this->takeoffCity = t_city;
        }
        void setLandingCity(std::string l_city){
        this->landingCity = l_city;
        }
        void setFlightDate(std::string d){
        this->flightDate = d;
        }
        void setHours(int h){
        this->hours = h;
        }
        void setMinutes(int m){
        this->minutes = m;
        }
       void setNumber(int n){
        this->flightNumber = n;
        }
        void setAmount(int a){
        this->amountofseats = a;
        }
        void addTicket(Ticket t){
        tickets.push_back(t);
        }
        std::string getCompany(){
        return company;
        }
        std::string getTakeoffCity(){
        return takeoffCity;
        }
        std::string getLandingCity(){
        return landingCity;
        }
        std::string getFlightDate(){
        return flightDate;
        }
        int getAmountOfSeats(){
        return amountofseats;
        }
        int getFlightNumber(){
        return flightNumber;
        }
        void getTime(){
        std::cout<<"the plane leaves at "<<hours<<"h "<<minutes<<"min "<<std::endl;
        }
        ~Flight(){}

    };

    class Airport
    {
    private:
        std::string name;
        std::vector <Ticket>tickets;
    public:
        void setNameAirport(std::string na){
        this->name = na;
        }
        void addTicket(Ticket t){
        tickets.push_back(t);
        }
        std::string getNameAirport(){
        return name;
        }
        ~Airport(){}
    };

    class City
    {
    private:
        std::string name;
        std::vector <Airport> airports;
    public:
        void setNameCity(std::string n){
        this->name = n;
        }
        void addAirport(Airport a){
        airports.push_back(a);
        }
        std::string getNameCity(){
        return name;
        }
        ~City(){}
    };

    class Base
    {
     private:
         std::vector <City>cities;
         std::vector <Airport>airports;
     public:
        void addCity(City c){
        cities.push_back(c);
        }
        void addAirport(Airport a){
        airports.push_back(a);
        }
    };



    class CityFactory
    {
    public:
         City* create(){
        return new City;
         }
         ~CityFactory(){}
     };

     class AirportFactory
     {
     public:
         Airport* create(){
         return new Airport;
         }
         ~AirportFactory(){}
     };

     class FlightFactory
    {
    public:
         Flight* create(){
         return new Flight();
         }
         ~FlightFactory(){}
    };
```

Comment: "сайта продажи билетов в консоли" чтобы это значило? Консольное приложение, где можно покупать билеты? Также ваш вопрос слишком общий, врядли кто-то за вас будет делать это задание.

Comment: Если нужны "окна" в консоли, то следует смотреть в сторону библиотек типа ncurses.